# How to copy file contents to a service during docker-compose up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 files:

```
.env
docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
  myapp:
    image: me/some-image
    depends_on:
      - database
    env_file: .env
```

myapp is a web service app that needs a .env file or optionally it can access the environment variables if no .env file is present.

As of now, the myapp is accessing the environment variables because I don't want the .env file to be included in the image build for security reasons. What I did is to pass a `env_file: .env` to the myapp service in the `docker-compose.yml` file so it will rely to the environment variables of the service instead of a .env file.

Now, I really want to add a .env file to the myapp service when running `docker-compose up`. Take note that the myapp web service will throw an error if it didnt find a .env file and the option is to look for a .env file instead of getting from the environment variables of the container.

Is there a way to create a .env file when running `docker-compose up` and copy the contents of the .env file on the host? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use bind mounts to bind your file from the host to override the file in the container. `volumes:
      - /dir/on/host/envfile:/path/in/container/envfile`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use bind mount to mount file into the container

change the target location to the one your app requires

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
  myapp:
    image: me/some-image
    depends_on:
      - database
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./.env
        target: /envfile/.env
        readonly: true
```

Comment: Looks like I will have to go with this one. Thanks for giving me ideas on volumes!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be storing the environment variables in the container.

According to [TwelveFactor](https://12factor.net/config)-

> The twelve-factor app stores config in environment variables (often shortened to env vars or env). Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any code; unlike config files, there is little chance of them being checked into the code repo accidentally; and unlike custom config files, or other config mechanisms such as Java System Properties, they are a language- and OS-agnostic standard.

You are correctly passing the env file. The env file needs to be in the format of `<key>=<value>`. 
For example -

```
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_SCHEMA=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_HOST=db

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_DB=0
```

In your application, you don't need to care about if the .env file is present, you simply read the environment variable.

Example in python -

```
import os
db_username = os.environ['DB_USERNAME']
```

You should not be coupling your environment variable to a file. It should read from the runtime environment.

Comment: Understood. But I just want to store the variables in the .env file, the web app is only the one who will access it. I don't want to access anything from the environment variables.

Comment: You lose the significance of having an environment variable file.
In your case, it could just be a .txt file where you read them from.